# How to POST multiple files, list of files to server using DIO in flutter

Tags: http, flutter, dart, dio

Files/fields be like :

```
jsonData,

List[images],

MultipartFile,
```

sending all these fields/files at once to server using DIO

Comment: read `dio`'s official documentation, they show how to do that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

resolved .. by refering to https://github.com/flutterchina/dio#sending-formdata

**Multiple files upload**

There are two ways to add multiple files to FormData， the only difference is that upload keys are different for array types。

```
  FormData.fromMap({
    "files": [
      MultipartFile.fromFileSync("./example/upload.txt",
          filename: "upload.txt"),
      MultipartFile.fromFileSync("./example/upload.txt",
          filename: "upload.txt"),
    ]
  });
```

The upload key eventually becomes "files[]"，This is because many back-end services add a middle bracket to key when they get an array of files. If you don't want “[]”，you should create FormData as follows（Don't use FormData.fromMap）:

```
  var formData = FormData();
  formData.files.addAll([
    MapEntry(
      "files",
       MultipartFile.fromFileSync("./example/upload.txt",
          filename: "upload.txt"),
    ),
    MapEntry(
      "files",
      MultipartFile.fromFileSync("./example/upload.txt",
          filename: "upload.txt"),
    ),
  ]);
```

Comment: Thank you my man @ajs.sonawane, I knew this was the issue but just wasn't able to find the solution. Thanks, man I was finding the solution for the last 3 days. God bless you

Comment: How can you achieve this in http library?

Comment: How to retries the list of images from php side though?

Answer (score 2):

```
"files": [
      await MultipartFile.fromFile("./text1.txt", filename: "text1.txt"),
      await MultipartFile.fromFile("./text2.txt", filename: "text2.txt"),
    ]
```

try add [] in "files[]":
es:

```
"files[]": [
      await MultipartFile.fromFile("./text1.txt", filename: "text1.txt"),
      await MultipartFile.fromFile("./text2.txt", filename: "text2.txt"),
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

From documents of [dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio):

"Uploading multiple files to server by FormData:"

```
FormData.fromMap({
    "name": "wendux",
    "age": 25,
    "file": await MultipartFile.fromFile("./text.txt",filename: "upload.txt"),
    "files": [
      await MultipartFile.fromFile("./text1.txt", filename: "text1.txt"),
      await MultipartFile.fromFile("./text2.txt", filename: "text2.txt"),
    ]
});
response = await dio.post("/info", data: formData);
```

Comment: Yes, I'm doing the same way , but the ```List<MultipartFile> multipartfile``` is not uploading to server.
and when tried ```multipartfile.elementAt(0)``` , it's taking .. not understanding what is the problem